404 error when running Jira plugin locally after updating Java SDK version
I have a Jira plugin I created. I recently updated my Java SDK to Oracle SDK 23 and am now getting a 404 error when I try to load http://localhost:2990/jira/.
Here is the text of the error page I get in the browser:
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.84

And here are the log messages:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Dec 12, 2024 11:07:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Server startup in [205209] milliseconds
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x started on port [2990]
[INFO] jira started successfully in 283s at http://localhost:2990/jira
[INFO] Type Ctrl-C to shutdown gracefully
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Dec 12, 2024 11:12:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1349)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1337)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1174)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.GsonStatsSerializer.buildGson(GsonStatsSerializer.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.GsonStatsSerializer.serialize(GsonStatsSerializer.java:25)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.JiraStats.log(JiraStats.java:468)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.JiraStats.printAndReset(JiraStats.java:418)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Dec 12, 2024 11:12:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.LongStats]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.LongStats]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1349)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1337)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1174)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.MutableLongStats.get(MutableLongStats.java:58)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.mention.stats.data.UserSearchServiceStatsData.getTotalMeasuredOperationsForStatsOverheadInMillis(UserSearchServiceStatsData.java:34)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.JiraStats.log(JiraStats.java:456)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.util.stats.JiraStats.printAndReset(JiraStats.java:418)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 

I think (but am not sure) that it's related to Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]. However, I haven't been able to find much on what this actually means. The closest I've been able to find is this, which is about a different error message with the same dependency (but doesn't seem to apply to my case).
In this case, someone was able to resolve a similar issue by shutting down their server and starting it over, but that didn't work for me.
I saw similar issues here and here on the Atlassian developer forum, but there was no answer to either post.
I already tried running atlas-clean and deleting the C:\Users\MyUser\.m2\repository folders, but neither helped.
I also checked java -version, and everything seems normal there:
java version "23.0.1" 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

atlas-version seemed ok too:
ATLAS Version:    8.2.7
ATLAS Home:       C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4
AMPS Version:     8.1.2
--------
Executing: "C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\mvn.cmd" --version -gs C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T13:33:14-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..
Java version: 23.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Can someone point me in the right direction?

You don't say which Jira version you are developing against, but the Atlassian docs for the latest Jira 10.3 at
https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/supported-platforms-938846830.html
show that Java23 is not yet supported. I would try using a supported version of Java for this

@mdoar Good to know - I'm not at my desk right now, but I'll try it out in the morning and let you know if I fix it. (I'm still on version 9.1 or something like that).

@mdoar That was actually very helpful, thanks.
